# Enviar parâmetro URL de uma tabela para um modal

Tags: url, modal, parâmetros

Bom dia amigos,
Estou com uma dúvida para enviar parâmetros URL como se fosse um;

```html
<a href=\"pagina.php?id=$id\" >enviar</a>
```

Só que ao invés de enviar para outra página, gostaria de enviar para um modal na mesma página. Alguma dica?

Comment: Colocar em que dentro do modal? Dentro de um input?

Comment: Opa Leo, tudo bem?
Então, imagine que tem uma tabela com vários nomes, aí para alterar informações dos usuarios, coloco o ID no href e mando para outra página, certo?
Porém, preciso ao invés de mandar para outra página, abrir um modal com o form que já tenha o ID do usuário e depois sim mandar para outra página que vá fazer o update ou insert, enfim.

É só abrir o modal já com informações do ID da tabela.
Ta meio confuso, eu sei kkkkk

Comment: Editei a resposta para adaptar a sua necessidade.

Comment: Caso alguma resposta resolveu seu problema, marque-a como aceita. Veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo passando o "parâmetro" para o `value` de um `input` seria assim:

```
<?php
session_start();

$connect = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

if (isset($_POST["campo"])) { 
    $id = $_POST["campo"];
    $_SESSION["id"]=$id;
    echo '<script>window.open("usuario/usuario.php");</script>'; 

}

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
function setaDadosModal(valor) {
    document.getElementById('campo').value = valor;
}
</script>

<?php

    $sql2="select * from nomeTabela";
    $listar=mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);

    $tabela .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

    $tabela .= '<table border="1">';

    $tabela .= '<tr>';

    $tabela .='<thead>';

    $tabela .= '<tr>';

    $tabela .= '<th>nome</th>';

    $tabela .='</thead>'; 

    $tabela .='<tbody>';


    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listar)) {

        $tabela .= '<tr>';

        //$tabela .= '<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="setaDadosModal(\''.$rows['id'].'\')">'.$rows['nome'].'</a></td>';

        $tabela .= '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="setaDadosModal(\''.$rows['id'].'\')">'.$rows['nome'].'</button></td>';

    }

    $tabela .= '</tr>';

    $tabela .='</tbody>'; 

    $tabela .= '</table>';

    $tabela .= '</div>';

    echo $tabela;

    mysqli_close($connect); 
?>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">ID</h4>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="md-form ml-0 mr-0">
                        <input type="text" name="campo" id="campo">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light" ><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></span> Enviar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar JS para isso, pois o modal não trafega dados por padrão.

Dá pra fazer isso tudo com apenas JS, mas para simplificar, vou dar uma ideia de como usar o mínimo de JS e simplificar seu trabalho:

Considerando que você usa `Boostrap`.

O seu HTML será algo assim:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="botaoAbreModal" data-toggle="modal" href='#meuModal' data-id="SUA VARIAVEL">Abre Modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="meuModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>

                /* Vamos colocar o input aqui dinamicamente */

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando o Modal for aberto, você pega o evento dele e injeta no seu form como um input, assim:

```
 $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        var id = $('#botaoAbreModal').attr('data-id');
        $('#meuModal form').append(`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${id}"`);
    });
```